# Aha!<>VSTS Integration - Aha! adjusted Stack Rank in VSTS - tips on reverting?

Tags: azure-devops, rank

While integrating with VSTS, I accidentally wiped out the stack rank in VSTS for my 100+ features. My first choice would be to undo the import. Does anyone know how I could revert the action on either the Aha or VSTS side? My second choice would be to edit one by one. I can go into the details of each story and see the original stack rank, but I can't seem to be able to find where I could then reenter it one by one.

Comment: Seems no way to revert, however in VSTS you can create a query and export the work items to excel, then edit them --> save --> publish back . See [Bulk add or modify work items with Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=vsts) for details.

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't any other action performed on these work items after that, the quick way is getting the Stack Rank value in the previous revision of the work items and updating the work items with the returned stack rand via coding. Following is the code sample to update the value of Stack Rank to previous version for a single work item:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;

namespace ConsoleX
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri url = new Uri("https://vstsaccount.visualstudio.com");
            TfsTeamProjectCollection ttpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(url);
            WorkItemStore wis = ttpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
            int workitemid = 12;
            WorkItem wi = wis.GetWorkItem(workitemid);
            int previousrevision = wi.Revision - 2;
            string previousstackrank = wi.Revisions[previousrevision].Fields["Stack Rank"].Value.ToString();
            wi.Fields["Stack Rank"].Value = previousstackrank;
            wi.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

For you scenario, just add some code to query that 100+ features and update them one by one.